# Расположение прикрепленных файлов в теле поста блога

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть небольшой блог. При создании записи в блоге, к ней можно прикрепить несколько файлов картинок. Вывод этих картинок на странице записи происходит так:

```
#show.html.slim
p = blog.title
p = blog.body
- blog.attachments.each do |a|
  = a.file.thumb
```

Таким образом все аттачменты выводятся после тела самой записи.

Хочется, чтобы при создании поста была возмножность "указывать" место где будет выводиться аттачмент. Т.е. чтобы было например так:

```
текст
аттачмент
текст
аттачмент
```

Answer (score 3):

Могу порекомендовать gem rich https://github.com/kreativgebiet/rich

Он содержит в себе текстовый редактор CKEditor и загрузчик файлов CKPicker. CKEditor - популярный WYSIWYG редактор, с возможностью загружать и вставлять файлы текст (при использовании CKPicker).

Может интегрироваться в панели администрирования Active Admin и Rails Admin, а также использоваться без них вместе с Formtastic (это gem для удобного конструирования форм).

Пример использования с Formtastic:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :featured_image, :as => :rich_picker %>
    <%= f.input :body, :as => :rich, :config => { :default_style => "myCrazyPaperclipStyle" } %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.buttons do %>
    <%= f.commit_button %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Строка `<%= f.input :featured_image, :as => :rich_picker %>` отрендерит загрузчик файлов, а строка `<%= f.input :body, :as => :rich, :config => { :default_style => "myCrazyPaperclipStyle" } %>` - редактор. В самом редакторе уже есть загрузчик, поэтому этот пример приведен только для демонстрации работы подгрузчика вне самого редактора.

Плюсы: богатый функционал самого редактора и возможность использования загрузчика как менеджера всех файлов на сайте, интеграция в панели администратора.

Минусы: нельзя использовать без Formtastic